# Limit selection of cells on multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to use jquery to limit the number of selected cells in each displayed table.

With some tinkering I managed to get some working code to limit the selection but cannot figure out how to distinguish between the tables (i.e. each table can have a max selection of 4 cells).

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/h18yr46a/6/)  to the  fiddle.

I have also posted the jquery below.

Thanks.

```
function selectCount () {
var num1;
 num1 =  $.grep($('td'),function(TD){
   return $(TD).css('background-color') == 'rgb(153, 153, 153)' ;
}).length;   
return num1;
}

$(function () {
var isMouseDown = false; 



 //    $(#$(this).closest('table').attr('id') "td")

$("#our_table td")
.mousedown(function () {
  isMouseDown = true;

    var sCount = selectCount();


    if (sCount < 4 || $(this).css('background-color')== 'rgb(153, 153, 153)')
  $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
  return false; // prevent text selection
})

.mouseover(function () {       
   var foo = selectCount();
  if (isMouseDown && sCount < 4 ||isMouseDown &&  $(this).css('background-color')== 'rgb(153, 153, 153)') {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
  }
});

$(document)
.mouseup(function () {
  isMouseDown = false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('table').on('click', function (e) {
    var ourTable = jQuery(e.target).closest('table');
    var sCount = ourTable.find('.highlighted').length;

    if (sCount < 4 || $(e.target).hasClass('highlighted')) {
        $(e.target).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h18yr46a/7/

You can actually reduce the whole thing down to four lines:

```
jQuery('table').on('click', function (e) {
    if (jQuery(this).find('.highlighted').length < 4 || $(e.target).hasClass('highlighted')) {
            $(e.target).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. My 10 hours of coding you did in minutes. Better code in half the space. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, its possible to get it down to four lines of code in the function itself